# sticky kit keep elements

Tags: jquery, html, sticky

I'm using sticky kit and i'm trying to make a vertical navbar.
Now the problem is I don't want that the elements disappear.
Here's an example:
http://es.22web.org/sticky-collapse.html (not my site found this in a other question here)

if you scroll down the section numbers scroll down till they reach the next element and then dissepears.
i'm trying to get the element to stay there so in the end you get

section 1

section 2

section 3

section 4

and not:

section 3

section 4

and section 1 en 2 gone

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x8cc6rgh/ but as you can see 1st disseppears

Comment: This is not what you've tried - this is running the script someone else made. You want something different, so my question is what you changed to make this happen. SO is not a tool for you to abuse in getting other people to do your work.

Comment: updated version: http://concept.enecs.org/sticky/ it kind of works but now i'm trying to make 2de and 3de stick at the bottom and when i scroll down and reach the paragraph the menu item has to go with it